# How to get the number of arrays generated by dividing an array into a tree, without actually doing the division?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, iteration

Assume we have an array of size `n`, and we conceptually run it through this `divide` function with `size == 5`, as in `divide(array_of_size_n, 5)`:

```
function divide(data, size) {
  const result = []

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += size) {
    const chunk = data.slice(i, i + size);
    result.push(chunk)
  }

  if (result.length > size) {
    return divide(result, size)
  }

  return result;
}
```

This will generate a *tree* where each node is no larger than 5 items in length.

The question is though, how many arrays does it create, without actually running the `divide` function and creating the arrays? What is the *equation* that will give you the number of arrays that would get computed, as in `getNumArrays(n)`? Is there a way to do this with an algorithm that is independent of the size of `n`? How can you generalize it to make it so instead of 5 items max per array, there were `m` items max per array?

---

Here is me trying to think it through...

So I am interested in getting this to work on arrays size 32.

So first, you fill up a 32-item array. Then this causes one above to appear, where now only it's first slot/child (the old 32-item array) is filled. Then we can add 31 more 32-item arrays. So 32 * 32 items. This then causes *another* level above to appear, which *I think* follows the same pattern, so 32 * 32 * 32.... Hmm... That tells us at least how many levels there are.

So does that mean, say we go to the path `2/2/2`:

```
32^(3-1) + 2
+ 32^(2-1) + 2
+ 32^(1-1) + 2
= 1026 + 34 + 2 = 1062 is the index?
```

Now I'm interested to find the reverse...

```
1026 = size^(depth - 1) + x
     + size^(depth - 2) + y
     + size^(depth - 3) + z
```

Now I'm lost lol.

Comment: Why is `upSize` declared but not used?

Comment: @גלעדברקן sorry about that, fixed!

Comment: do you want exact calculation or upper bound?

Comment: the recursive formula is T(n) = ceil(n/m) + T(ceil(n/m)) , you can easily create a function to solve that without creating the actual arrays.  it will be faster, but still dependent on n.

Comment: @ChristianSloper ok, so there's no way without depending on n? How would the calculation work? I would like the exact calculation.

Comment: I mean it is strictly dependent on n, as n grows the number of arrays grow too.  But maybe you mean a closed form (non recursive). It is maybe possible, but beyond me :-)   Creating a function to solve the recursion without creating arrays i can give below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So recursive function is:

```
f(n,m) = ceil(n/m) + f( ceil(n/m), n)
```

Computing exact closed form solutions of recursive functions with floor and ceilings isn't trivial (at least not to me :-) ).  We can create a simple recursive function for it like this, it is faster than simulating with arrays as is simply integer division.

```
def f(n, m):
    if ceil(n/m) <= m:
        return ceil(n/m)
    return ceil(n/m) + f(ceil(n/m),m)
```

(this can be made faster by just a simple while loop i guess.)

Some results:

```
f(25,5) = 5   # 25 elements grouped into exactly 5 arrays

f(26,5) = 8   # 25 elements grouped into 6 arrays, which again are grouped into two arrays
```

The number of levels will be log_m(n), at each level the number of elements are reduced by a factor of m.

Comment: This is excellent, now I'm wondering how to do it with while loops haha. I'll mark this as correct unless someone turns out to know how to find a solution that doesn't depend on `n`. Thank you so much!

Comment: @LancePollard `int f = 0; while (n>0) { f += (n = (n+m-1)/m); } return f;`